# stucking logical operator in WHILE statement

Tags: loops, while-loop, pascal, logical-operators

[image]

as you can see my picture above, i have problem with logical operators, so i need a looping program for searching data, my parameter can be filled with game_code or game_title, but there are some problem in the looping sequence.

so how to solve this problem, i tried this but not work

```
begin
          write(#32'Enter Game Title or Code: '); readln(param);
          i:=1;
          while((data[i].game_title<>param) or (data[i].game_code<>param)) and (i<totaldata) do
               i:=i+1;
          if (data[i].game_title=param) or (data[i].game_code=param) then
```

Comment: This expression: `(data[i].game_title<>param) or (data[i].game_code<>param)` will only be `false` if `data[i].game_title` and `data[i].game_code` are all the same value, and `param` is different from that value. Is that what you intend?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a parenthesis. try this and let me know:

```
while(((data[i].game_title=param) or (data[i].game_code=param)) and (i<totaldata)) do
    begin
        i:=i+1;
    end;
```

Comment: still :) 
Data not found
because the game_title and game_code record not looping

Comment: i changed your operator from `<>` to `=`

Comment: The outer parentheses are unnecessary, as are the `begin` and `end` in this context and won't matter.

Answer (score -1):

You should go with `and`:

```
while (i < totaldata) and (data[i].game_title <> param) and (data[i].game_code <> param) do
    i:=i+1;
```

The `or` expression  `(data[i].game_title <> param) or (data[i].game_code <> param)` will always be `true` until `game_title = game_data = param`.

Note that `i < totaldata` check must be done first to avoid access to memory out of array bounds.